# Defined color under res not usable in code

Tags: android

I defined a white color in mycolors.xml under res/values as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
<color name="my_white">#ffffffff</color>
</resources>
```

In my code, I set the text color of a TextView as the white color I defined:

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
myText.setTextColor(R.color.my_white);
```

But the text in the TextView turned out to be a black color.

When I use @color/my_white in layout xml files, it works fine.

I check the generate R.java, and see:

public static final int my_white=0x7f070025;

Did I miss something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`R.color.my_white` is an ID that contains a reference to your resource. `setTextColor` expects you pass a color, not a reference. The code compiles and gives no errors because `setTextColor` expect an `int`; but, of course, you are giving the wrong `int`. In this case, you will have to *convert* the reference to a integer that represents that color:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int color = res.getColor(R.color.my_white);
myText.setTextColor(color);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Android developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color), it looks like your reference should be:

```
myText.setTextColor(R.color.my_white);
```

ETA: As noted in Mayra's answer, R.id.my_white is probably returning a reference to the object that represents your colour rather than the ARGB value of the colour.

Comment: There is a typo in my question. Actually, my code is writing: myText.setTextColor(R.color.my_white);

Comment: Have you tried following the later part of the doc where it gives an example of retrieving the colour resource?

Comment: I got it. The correct way to write the code should be: myText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ff_white));  

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are providing setTextColor currently is the id of the my_white object, not the color my_white.  I think what you want is `R.color.my_white`.

Comment: There is a typo in my question. Actually, my code is writing: myText.setTextColor(R.color.my_white);